# Convert HTML string to Javascript document instructions

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Is there an convenient way to convert an HTML string to **JavaScript instructions that would produce the same markup** with the DOM.

Something along the lines of:

### Input

```html
<div class="foo" tabindex="4">
  bar
  <button title="baz">bar</button>
</div>
```

### Output

```js
let a = document.createElement('div');
a.classList.add('foo');
a.setAttribute('tabindex', '4');
let b = document.createTextNode('bar');
a.appendChild(b);
let c = document.createElement('button');
c.setAttribute('title', 'baz');
let d = document.createTextNode('bar');
a.appendChild(d);
```

Comment: Im curious why you would want to deconstruct an html string into javascript code to just go about recreating the same string?

Comment: It sounds a bit like you are trying to reinvent React and JSX; is there any particular reason for not using React?

Comment: ...or simply with jQuery : `$("body").append( someHTMLstring )`

Answer (score 0):

With a little research you can find this function:

```
function stringToElement(string) {
    var parser = new DOMParser();
    var content = 'text/html';
    var DOM = parser.parseFromString(string, content);

    // return element
    return DOM.body.childNodes[0];
}
stringToElement('<li>text</li>') // OUTPUT: <li>text</li>
```

And I think this is what you want...

Answer (score 0):

If what you really need/want is to convert html string to DOM element, you have `DOMparser`

Sample:

```js
var phrase = "<div id='foo'><a href='#'>Link</a><span></span></div>";
var doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(phrase, "text/xml");
```

You can use that with a template string to put yout html